# project that depends of other project class usage

Tags: c#, .net, class, dependencies, dependency-properties

Having 3 projects inside a solution forming a structure like:

**GUI <- Implementation <- DataAcess**

I have a class inside GUI `visualBic` that gets its properties filled after user interacts.

The problem I have is to pass those properties to `DataAcess` project.
What I can do is to use `dataccess` inside implementation as Implementation is one level up... but can not use GUI in implementation as Implementation is one level down...

When tried filling database in Implementation, as I do not have GUI `visualBic` class inside Implementation project, I was not able to do so... 
I can not create an instance, or add a reference of GUI in Implementation project, because that would create a  circular dependency

The question is how can I use a class in GUI project inside Implementation project not causing circular dependency ?

I could move GUI `visualBic` class to Implementation project, but GUI `visualBic` class uses some stuff that is only GUI (dlls), and that stuff can not live in Implementation project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the `visualBic` class is not the class to be passing to the implementation! As you noted, it has UI specific fields/logic and so is not suitable for living in the "Implementation" project where it would have to for classes in that project to know about it.

The answer to your question is you don't EVER want a reference from "Implementation" to the GUI because that tightly couples the two, completely defeating the purpose of separating them in the first place (even if it was technically possible).

Instead, you need a new object that CAN live in "Implementation" that your GUI fills out and passes to the appropriate function.

My `visualBic`: (in GUI assembly)

```
public class visualBic
{
   public String Name {get; set;}
   ... Bunch of other, potentially GUI stuff
}
```

BicDTO: (In Implementation assembly)

```
public class BicDTO
{
    public String Name {get; set;}
}
```

Translation function: (In GUI assembly)

```
public void SendImplementationData(visualBic data)
{
   BicDTO implementationObject = new BicDTO();
   implementationObject.Name = data.Name;
   implementationRef.SendData(implementationObject);
}
```

Obviously this is highly generalized, but it should get the point across. Let me know if I can clarify anything else!

Comment: is there a way to create a class in implementation that inherits from GUI or something... Also I was thinking on cloning object...

Comment: Could you please post  sample code to see how it would look like? How to fill Implementation object with GUI object?

Comment: Updated with sample code. Please let me know what you think!

Comment: I think I get it...  I need to create object in GUI that references Implementation, and create a method that sends GUI data to Implementation, then in Implementation I would call `SendImplementationData` is that correct?

Comment: In short, I must create a class that has same properties of GUI class, then That object lives in Implementation but I have copied all values...

Comment: The GUI calls "SendImplementationData" with the filled out object. Other than that, I believe you understand my example correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you can't.  If you need to use a type in Implementation then it must either be defined in Implementation or else defined in a separate project that both Implementation and GUI reference.  You would then map the data from your `visualBic` class to this other class and pass that down to Implementation.

Comment: Is there a way to pass information from GUI to Implementation?

Comment: If there wasn't then why would I suggest doing it a particular way in my answer above?

Comment: Why are you looking for an exotic way to do this?  Just do what many thousands of developers the world over already do and what more than one person here has already told you to do.  It's not hard.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [Data Transfer Objects](http://adnan.chohdry.com/development/dto-data-transfer-object/) for passing data, properties, etc between your layers/projects.  Create a separate DTO project and keep your DTOs there.  The you can ref them across all other projects.

You can create the DTO in your UI layer, fill it, then pass it to your Implementation layer to apply rules/change values then pass it again to your data access layer for persistence, etc.

Another [DTO link](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html)